# Django conditional post-save signal

Tags: django, signals, receiver

Trying to trigger a post-save signal when a certain boolean in the model is True.

To clear things up, my current receiver is

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Activity,   dispatch_uid="create_feed_receiver")
```

I wanna be able to do something like this:

```
 @receiver(post_save, sender=(Activity, boolean =True) dispatch_uid="create_feed_receiver")
```

Is there any way to achieve this. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

What about this,

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Activity,   dispatch_uid="create_feed_receiver")
def my_signal(instance, created, **kwargs):
    if instance.your_model_field:
        do something
```

here `instance` is your `Activity` class instance which is just saved.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I ended up doing eventually. My question was more about doing it through the connector.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, Its not possible through connecters. I think this is more convenient way to so.